# Which graph algorithm should I use for finding quickest route through all given destinations?

Tags: java, math, graph

I'm creating a Java program that will be calculating the quickest route between all given destinations, starting from a user selected one. It's a trip planner - you start in a base, visit all destinations and get back to base. Places and connections between them are represented by a directed weighted graph. There are always both routes A->B and B->A, but their length may vary. Places can be visited multiple times, especially if it can help shortening the total distance.

I'm quite confused about all of this. I thought about implementing the DFS algorithm and prioritizing routes by shortest length. What would you suggest?

Comment: This question is also known as the [travelling salesman problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Travelling_salesman_problem).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an [NP-Hard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NP-hardness) problem known as the **Traveling Salesman Problem**. As the number of cities to visit grows, the number of possible paths grows exponentially.

For examples where the distance between cities satisfies the **triangle inequality** (such as regular Euclidian distance), you can use the [branch and bound](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/traveling-salesman-problem-using-branch-and-bound-2/) algorithm to get a solution that is at most a constant multiple worse than the optimal solution.

For heuristic approaches, beam search algorithms like genetic algorithms can be used to find approximate solutions.